# Why does Mathematica not see some of the function PxB1[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, c11_, c12_] variables?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, numerical-integration, function-construction

Why does Mathematica not see the c11 and c12 variables in the function PxB1[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, c11_, c12_]? How to fix it?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
imax = 1; jmax = 2;
Psi[r_, z_, i_, j_] := Exp[-b[j]*z^2]*Exp[-a[i]*r^2];
c[i_, j_] := Symbol["c" <> ToString[i] <> ToString[j]]
a[1] = a1;
b[1] = b1;
Do[a[i] = a[i - 1] qa, {i, 2, imax}];
Do[b[j] = b[j - 1] qb, {j, 2, jmax}];
VB[r_, z_] = -(1/(2*Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]))*Exp[-Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]*1/2];
Px1B1[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] := 
  Block[{a1 = a10, b1 = b10, qa = qa0, qb = qb0}, 
   NIntegrate[
    Psi[r, z, i2, j2]*VB[r, z]*Psi[r, z, i1, j1]*r, {r, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]];
(*Px1B1[1.22,0.44,1.40,1.81,1,2,1,1]
-0.18717992373162834`*)
PxB1[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, c11_, c12_] := 
  2 Pi Sum[c[i1, j1] c[i2, j2] Px1B1[a10, b10, qa0, qb0, i1, j1, i2, 
      j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];

PxB1[1.22, 0.44, 1.40, 1.81, 1, 2]


Out[1410]= 2 (-0.202823 c11^2 - 0.37436 c11 c12 - 
   0.175471 c12^2) \[Pi]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is much better if you make a small example of the issue. Sometimes when you make a small example, you'll find the problem your self. What I think you are asking is this

```
p = 3*a + b;
ClearAll[foo];
foo[a_, b_] := Module[{},
  Print[p]
  ]
foo[9, 6]
```

And you are asking why `p` do not print as `3*9+6` or `33`  Is this correct?

If so, it is simply because Mathematica sees `a` and `b` in the arguments as `9` and `6`. So by the time the call is made, inside `foo`, there is only numbers `9` and `6`. So the global `p` still have its `a` and `b` as symbols.

To workaround this, you can do

```
p = 3*a + b;
ClearAll[foo];
foo[aa_, bb_] := Module[{},
  Print[p /. {a -> aa, b -> bb}]
  ]
foo[9, 6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The arguments passed in `a` and `b` are not the same `a` and `b` inside your global variable. These are just numbers.

---

Another possibility is that you could be asking why the following does not work as you expect:

```
p = 3*a + b;
ClearAll[foo];
foo[a0_, b0_] := Module[{a = a0, b = a0},
  Print[p]
  ]
foo[9, 6]
```

This still gives `3 a+b` and not `33`. This is because when you do `{a = a0, b = a0}`, these *do not* assign values to the global `a,b`. These `a,b` are module local variables and have different context even though on the screen the names look the same.

If this is not what you are asking let me know so I can delete this.

Comment: Thank you very much! That is, if we now turn to the code, then I need to add one more line? `PxB11[a10_, b10_, qa0_, qb0_, c111_, c121_] :=   Module[{},    PxB1[a10, b10, qa0, qb0] /. {c11 -> c111, c12 -> c121}]`

Answer (score 3):

Your definition does not evaluate with `:=` inside `Sum`, because the definition of c involves argument list checking.

To avoid generation of a complete variables list first, replace the definition by giving `c` a general definition

```
       c = Symbol[StringJoin[ "c", ToString[##]] &;
```